# What are AlignmentDirectional and AlignmentGeometry in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I understand `alignment: Alignment(-1, 0),` and `alignment: Aignment.topLeft,` etc. but what are `AlignmentDirectional`, `AlignmentGeometry`. I can't understand the docs very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AlignmentGeometry` is the abstract type which `Alignment` and `AlignmentDirectional` implement. The whole idea is to define the relative positioning of two widgets (mostly a child and its parent). It has abstract methods to calculate result of interactions between two, scaling, adding, .... These methods are implemented by `Alignment` and `AlignmentDirectional`.

`Alignment` adds more details and helper functions, like the ones you mentioned: `Alignment(-1, 0)`, `Aignment.topLeft`, .... And this is what we most of the times use.

`AlignmentDirectional` is just like `Alignment` but is aware of TextDirection. It is useful in Left-to-Right languages where you want the horizontal direction to be automatically based on the TextDirection without you having to do any more calculations. As the doc says:

> This can be used to indicate an offset from the left in
> TextDirection.ltr text and an offset from the right in
> TextDirection.rtl text without having to be aware of the current text
> direction.

Comment: what do you mean by `be automatically based on the TextDirection without you having to do any more calculations.` ?

Comment: The direction will follow what you set by TextDirection and the calculations are automatically done to flow text accordingly.